# log4net with MinimalLock locking model not working when setting file name programmatically

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

When dynamically setting the log file name, the `RollingFileAppender` used with the `log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock` locking model
does not seem to log anything to the file.  However, when using the appender without this locking model, logging works.

In the config file below, `Appender1` works, but `Appender2` does not:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="Appender2"
    type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogName}" />
      <encoding value="utf-8" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10000KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="[%logger] %message%n" />
      </layout>
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    </appender>
    <appender name="Appender1"
    type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogName}" />
      <encoding value="utf-8" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10000KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="myLogger" additivity="false">
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="Appender2" />
    </logger>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="Appender1" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Here is the sample code I am testing:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("myLogger");
    GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = "Log1.log"; // <== The log file name is getting set here.  
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(@"Logger.config"));

    logger.Info("Sample log entry");
}
```

Another observation I made is that if I remove the root level logger, logging seems to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have to add the

```
 <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```

to both appenders, it is not present in Appender1. This will explain why removing the root element works.

Comment: Is it not possible to have appenders with differing locking models?

Comment: Yes, but each file the appenders write to should have the same locking model.